# spring boot redis boolean value is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

I am trying to get data from redis using crudRepository but it is not filtering by the boolean field. When I write `repository.findAll()` i am getting a list of objects and this object list's elements has a `false` field as I saved. But if I write a query for filtering just 'false' ones, it is returning only an empty array. Here is my code:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@RedisHash("StateData")
public class StateDataCache implements Serializable {
  @Id String id;
  private String deviceId;
  private String topic;
  private String message;
  private String lat;
  private String lon;
  private boolean isActive;
}


@Repository
public interface StateDataCacheRepository extends CrudRepository<StateDataCache, String> {
  List<StateDataCache> findAllByActiveFalseAndDeviceId(String deviceId);
  List<StateDataCache> findAllByActiveIs(boolean sent);
  List<StateDataCache> findAllByActiveFalse();
}


@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories
public class RedisConfig {

  @Value("${spring.data.redis.host}")
  private String redisHost;

  @Value("${spring.data.redis.port}")
  private int redisPort;

  @Bean
  public LettuceConnectionFactory redisStandAloneConnectionFactory() {
    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHost, redisPort));
  }

  @Bean
  public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(redisStandAloneConnectionFactory());
    return template;
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide the method invocations, including the one with the filter, that don't work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue. In my case, the attribute that I wanted to query for was serialized as "true" or "false" and therefore I had to change my repository methods to use a String instead of a boolean for querying. As in your case, deserializing worked fine, so if I did a findAll() and then filter by the boolean attribute, it was also working fine.

This did not work:

```
List<Object> findByAttribute(boolean attribute);
```

This worked:

```
List<Object> findByAttribute(String attribute);
```

Of course, I had to manually convert my boolean attribute into "true" or "false" before calling the method.